# override date format in mvc 3 with globalization set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, globalization

I have a mvc website using razor where the globalization is set to auto and it is using the clients preferred culture.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

What I'd like to know is there a way to force a date that is being bound via razor to show in a specific format ignoring the culture?

For example if I have a model

```
public class someObj
{
  public DateTime someDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I bind it like so in the view:

```
@Model.someDateTime
```

Can I override the preferred culture that the browser wants?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `@Model.SomeDate.ToString("Some Format", new CultureInfo(...))`

Comment: I actually found that the following worked for me:

    String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"),"{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}",Model.someDateTime)